# How to delete multiple nodes in XML using SQL

Tags: sql, xml, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have a column name XMLData which contain large XML (around 10,000 lines). 
Below is the type of XML stored.

```
<ABC>
  <DEF>
    <GHI>
      <JKL>value1</JKL>
      ..
    </GHI>
    <GHI>
      <JKL>value2</JKL>
      ..
    </GHI>
    <GHI>
      <JKL>value3</JKL>
      ..
    </GHI>
    ..
    ..
    <GHI>
      <JKL>valueN</JKL>
      ..
    </GHI>
    <OtherNodes>
    <OtherNodes1>
    .
    .
    .
  </DEF>
</ABC>
```

Is there a way to delete multiple nodes in SQL query? Specifically, I want to delete all GHI nodes under the Node DEF. Thanks!!

Comment: It probably more efficient to export, row, modify, xml, the update row.  If you are using SQL Server I recommend on of the command line executable like sqlcmd.exe or bcp.exe.  See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162816.aspx

Comment: @jdweng - do you have a specific reason for avoiding the SQL Server `xml` data type functionality (I'm always happy to learn something new)

Comment: It is easier to parse xml outside sql than inside.  Outside you can use other languages not avaiable inside.  You can put the call to the command language inside other programs using SHELL for example.

Answer (score 2):

For SQL Server, you'd just use [`modify`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/ms187093.aspx) with [`delete`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/ms190254.aspx):

```
declare @x xml = '<ABC>
  <DEF>
    <GHI>
      <JKL>value1</JKL>
    </GHI>
    <GHI>
      <JKL>value2</JKL>
    </GHI>
    <GHI>
      <JKL>value3</JKL>
    </GHI>
    <GHI>
      <JKL>valueN</JKL>
    </GHI>
    <OtherNodes/>
    <OtherNodes1/>
  </DEF>
</ABC>'

set @x.modify('delete /ABC/DEF/GHI')

select @x
```

Result:

```
<ABC><DEF><OtherNodes /><OtherNodes1 /></DEF></ABC>
```